# How can I paginate an array of objects in Laravel?

Tags: laravel-4, pagination, pivot-table

I'm building an application using Laravel 4.2. I have a model for `units` and another for `users` and pivot table `user_units`. Every user in this application can select a unit and add it to his favorite list then he can publish this unit with his information as an ad.

I want to select all units published by all users

The `user_units` (pivot) table has the following columns:

```
id   
user_id 
unit_id 
publish      
adtype       
addinfo          
created_at  
updated_at
```

With relations methods on models

```
public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'user_units')
                ->withPivot('id','publish', 'adtype', 'addinfo');
}

public function units() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Unit', 'user_units')
                ->withPivot('id','publish', 'adtype', 'addinfo');
}
```

My query to select all published units by all users

```
// Get all published units by users for sale. 
    $users = User::all();
    $publishedSaleUnits = [];
    foreach($users as $user){
        $userUnits = $user->units()->orderBy('adtype', 'desc')->get();
        if(count($userUnits)){
            foreach($userUnits as $unit){
                if($unit->pivot->publish == 1 && $unit->unit_purpose_id == 1){
                    if( $unit->pivot->adtype ){
                        //push all featured ads onto the beginning of array
                        array_unshift($publishedSaleUnits, $unit);
                    }else{
                        //push all normal ads onto the end of array
                        array_push($publishedSaleUnits, $unit);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I got the result but I can't use pagination with results because it's an array of objects.

So is there any better solution to get all published units by user with pagination?

Answer (score 33):

according to this article
https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/how-to-create-pagination-from-array-in-laravelexample.html

you can paginate your array by creating a custom method and using LengthAwarePaginator

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
  
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;
  
class PaginationController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $myArray = [
            ['id'=>1, 'title'=>'Laravel CRUD'],
            ['id'=>2, 'title'=>'Laravel Ajax CRUD'],
            ['id'=>3, 'title'=>'Laravel CORS Middleware'],
        ];
  
        $data = $this->paginate($myArray);
        return view('paginate', compact('data'));
    }
   
    public function paginate($items, $perPage = 5, $page = null, $options = [])
    {
        $page = $page ?: (Paginator::resolveCurrentPage() ?: 1);
        $items = $items instanceof Collection ? $items : Collection::make($items);
        return new LengthAwarePaginator($items->forPage($page, $perPage), $items->count(), $perPage, $page, $options);
    }
}
```

Comment: perfect answer.

Comment: Same example Not working in API for laravel 8

Comment: Tested and tweaked a bit to use on my code using laravel 8.

Answer (score 6):

Your approach to query the data is extremely inefficient. Fetch your data in one query. Nested traversing is not only hard to read but also a performance killer.

To the pagination problem:

Laravel provides a Pagignator Factory. With it you will be able to build your own Paginator with your own data.

It's as easy as

```
$units = Paginator::make($unit, count($unit), 10);
```

if you're using the Facade. Otherwise `Illuminate\Pagination\Factory` is the class you are looking for.

Comment: $units = Paginator::make($units, count($units), 10);
i try this method before it create $units->links() in view perfect but every page contains all results from $units array

Comment: i have used paginator::make to paginate the records in the $publishedSaleUnits array. But in view i am getting the pagination links, but all links has all records in it. how to restrict it to perPage items.

Answer (score 4):

You can try my code with your own array,

```
$page = isset($request->page) ? $request->page : 1; // Get the page=1 from the url
$perPage = $pagination_num; // Number of items per page
$offset = ($page * $perPage) - $perPage;

$entries =  new LengthAwarePaginator(
    array_slice($contact_list, $offset, $perPage, true),
    count($contact_list), // Total items
    $perPage, // Items per page
    $page, // Current page
    ['path' => $request->url(), 'query' => $request->query()] // We 
       need this so we can keep all old query parameters from the url
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I got a better solution to paginate array result and I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23870493/how-to-use-paginatormake-in-laravel-to-show-resultset-in-view)

`Paginator::make` function we need to pass only the required values instead of all values. Because `paginator::make` function simply displays the data send to it. To send the correct offset paginated data to the `paginator::make`, the following method should be followed

```
    $perPage = 5;   
    $page = Input::get('page', 1);
    if ($page > count($publishedSaleUnits) or $page < 1) { $page = 1; }
    $offset = ($page * $perPage) - $perPage;
    $perPageUnits = array_slice($publishedSaleUnits,$offset,$perPage);
    $pagination = Paginator::make($perPageUnits, count($publishedSaleUnits), $perPage);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Laravel 8, if any of you are having trouble in the paginator getting lost with the URL after page 1, just add in the `LengthAwarePaginator` `options` parameter the URL path for you original page.

Example:

```
return new LengthAwarePaginator($items->forPage($page, $perPage), $items->count(), $perPage, $page, ['path' => 'users']);
```

Answer (score 0):

this code work for me on laravel 8

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;


    public function paginate($items, $perPage = 5, $page = null, $options = [])
    {
        $page = $page ?: (Paginator::resolveCurrentPage() ?: 1);
        $items = $items instanceof Collection ? $items : Collection::make($items);
        return new LengthAwarePaginator($items->forPage($page, $perPage), $items->count(), $perPage, $page, $options);
    }
```

according to this refrence https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/how-to-create-pagination-from-array-in-laravelexample.html

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
<?php

namespace App\Utils;

use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;
use \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;

class Paginate
{
    public static function paginate($items, $perPage = 10, $page = null)
    {
        $page = $page ?: (Paginator::resolveCurrentPage() ?: 1);
        $total = count($items);
        $currentpage = $page;
        $offset = ($currentpage * $perPage) - $perPage ;
        $itemstoshow = array_slice($items , $offset , $perPage);


        return new LengthAwarePaginator($itemstoshow, $total, $perPage, $page,
            ['path'=> Request::fullUrl()]);
    }
}
```

You can visit this link as well:
[Laravel Create Pagination From Array Tutorial](https://www.laravelia.com/post/laravel-create-pagination-from-array-tutorial)