# Is Paginator::make still available in Laravel 5.5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, pagination, laravel-5.5

I am trying to use `Paginator::make` on my array data with Laravel 5.5. I found an answer on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27064953/how-can-i-paginate-an-array-of-objects-in-laravel), but the function is not working.
I cannot find `Paginator::make` in the documentation either.

Comment: you can do this in 5.5 `$paginator = new Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator($items, $perPage, $currentPage);` inject the class and then use it.

Comment: Did you try to use paginate method in your Eloquent model ?