# Is it possible simplify this query to work with paginator (without creating a custom paginator)?

Tags: sql, laravel

I have list of messages by users and I need to get the oldest message of each user, then use `paginate()` on the result.

example data:

```
id | user_id |     message    | date_posted
1  |    5    |  some_message  |  2022-07-15  
2  |   125   |  some_message  |  2022-08-02  
3  |    5    |  some_message  |  2022-04-05
```

So in this case I need to get only rows with id `2` and `3`

The problem is that I got this complex query to do it, and I have to use it inside `DB::select(DB::raw($query));`, which returns an array, and `paginate` can't be used on array.

This is the query:

```
select T.*
from (select *,
             row_number() over (partition by user_id order by date_posted, id) as sn
      from my_table
     ) T
where sn = 1;
```

Is there a way to get these results with statements that can be converted to Query Builder or Eloquent?

*I can't disable `only_full_group_by`

Comment: Could you create a model to handle the pivot to return an eloquent model which you can then handle with pagination? There are limitations of the orm. By running a raw query you are essentially reaching outside the knowledge of the orm. Therefore it's only option is to return an array. If you create a model for this then eloquent then has knowledge and handle it like you expect.

Comment: I think it's impossible in my case, but I might not understand you right? Since my DB is handled not by me and it's a Microsoft SQL server. Could you provide an example?

Comment: Basically you are asking the model to create a piece of data created on the fly and expecting eloquent eloquent on the fly to know how to handle that without a definition. Therefore assuming it would conform to the expectations of orm...

Comment: So you mean I need create some model called `GetUniqueMessages`, which will fetch the data I need (do the query above), then return it. Then when I call the model it will return this data as the ORM object: `GetUniqueMessages::get();`?

Comment: Yep, that is exactly what I mean.

Comment: Without that how could eloquent have knowledge of the runtime query meets it's requirements? Therefore how could it know if it abides it's rules.

Comment: I just missed one part: to do this query inside the Model's method, not directly `GetUniqueMessages::get();`, but actually it should be `GetUniqueMessages::getMessages()->get();`

Comment: There are many ways to approach this but basically you can relationships, queries, quiry scopes, etc... The main point is you need to return a model that extends eloquent to run eloquent methods.

Comment: An array has zero knowledge of eloquent and vice versa

Comment: Understood, I will try to do the model approach. Otherwise, I will create my own custom paginator. In fact I already made it, but the pagination links are broken. Will see which one works better. thank you

Comment: I feel like a custom pagination is to specific. I could be wrong, only because you will need one for each query and will have redundant code. However if it works 

Comment: Check this out: You can get a relatively general paginate method:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/63392687/19815685

Comment: Basically creating the models are a lot easier to make and are like 30 lines per file vs a 200 line pagination file that refuses code.

Comment: Alright then I am trying the model approach now :D

Comment: Ya in your example, see what I'm saying. They are using logic specific to the query. Just make the model and have the power of eloquent, relationships, etc...

Comment: But now I wonder - do I need a new model for that, or I can just put that query inside a method in the `Messages` model, then get it like `Messages::getUniqueMessages()`?

Comment: That's even easier. Sorry I don't know your whole use case but basically if you can keep the orm in play you can leverage it.

Comment: Like is said previously you can utilize a bunch of approaches to return a model. So as long as you return a model that extends eloquent you can leverage it's power.

Comment: Second you start using db or raw.. you are gonna return arrays and loose that leverage.

Comment: Ya also it sounds like you may want to use a query scope for your exact case. Look it up.

Answer (score 1):

I'm solve the problem with this sql command:

```
select MIN(id) AS id, user_id, MIN(date_posted) AS date_posted, substring_index(GROUP_CONCAT(message), ',', 1) AS message from `messages` group by `user_id` order by `date_posted` asc
```

if you need Laravel code:

```
    $message = Message::
    selectRaw("MIN(id) AS id, user_id,
     MIN(date_posted) AS date_posted,
     substring_index(GROUP_CONCAT(message), ',', 1) AS message")
    ->groupBy('user_id')
    ->orderBy('date_posted')
    ->get();
```

if you need paginate just insted of `get` write `paginate()`

Comment: Yup and to my point. This answer demonstrates utilizing the model.

Comment: This doesn't work, I get the same error of `column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause`. (This is why I said at the end of the post that I can't disable `only_full_group_by`). Is there a way to make this query work with this constraint?

Comment: yes what column you need in data?

Comment: you can use aggregate function like `MIN()` or `SUM()` if you need jsut the data you can use `MIN()` or `MAX`